# Understanding Vapnik's Regression Function in Statistical Learning Theory

Tags: regression

I am struggling to understand what is meant by Equation 1.8 in Vapnik's Statistical Learning Theory. Vapnik introduces the equation below as the *regression* function.

$ r(x) = \int y\ dF(y|x) $

I know that $x$ and $y$ are random variables -- where $x$ is an input and $y$ should be the outcome. I know $F(y|x)$ is the conditional probability distribution where

$F(y|x) = \frac{F(y,x)}{F(x)}$

But I don't understand what is $r(x)$. What does it mean to integrate a random variable, $y$, w.r.t. $dF(y|x)$ ?

To try and be more clear about my confusion, if I were to assume the joint space: $F(x,y)$ looked similar to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Multivariate_normal_sample.svg , Then my $F(y|x)$ would be a normal distribution for some $x=c$ where $c$ is a constant.

So, $F(y|x=c)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}exp((\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma})^2)$, and when I plug this example into the original equation I get:

$ r(x) = \int y\ d(\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}exp((\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma})^2)) $

I am really confused because (1) I have no clue how one would perform this integration;
(2) I have no idea what I'm actually integrating here.

I am also looking for more probability-calculus resources because I know I am weak in understanding this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. And thank you for reading and helping!

Comment: As yourself said, all of your confusions can be answered after a good study of "probability-calculus", in particular integration theory.  To this end, check relevant chapters in classical probability texts, such as Billingsley, Chung, Williams, etc.  For a quicker route, search "Lebesgue integration, Riemann-Stieltjes integration" in Wikipedia to get some explanations on notations such as "$dF$", at least.

Comment: Thank you so much for the direction!!